# Subclass member variable's visibility to another subclass

Tags: java, inheritance, visibility

I am running a test program to know more about member variables' visibility, and I created the following 3 classes:

**ParentClass.java**

```
public class ParentClass {
    protected int mMember;
}
```

**ChildClass.java**

```
public class ChildClass extends ParentClass {
    ChildClass() {
        mMember = 10;
    }
}
```

**ChildChildClass.java**

```
public class ChildChildClass extends ChildClass {
    ChildChildClass() {
        mMember = 5;
    }
}
```

What is the *access level* of the `ChildChildClass`'s `mMember` variable ? Is it **public** or **protected** ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would remain protected unlike in C++ where depending on the type of inheritance (public, protected or private) it remains the same.

The main reason C++ allows such inheritance is that it supports multiple inheritance. However, Java doesn't support it. Hence, it just simplifies it by keeping the access level as in super class.

Answer (score 2):

`mMember` in `ChildChildClass` is inherited from `ParentClass`, and the visibility does not change - hence it is still `protected`

Comment: I looked it up in the JavaDocs but I can't seem to find anything relevant about it. Any proof ?

Comment: @JDev - you can just try it and get your proof (or trust me :))

Comment: The proof is just because you extended the parent class, it doesn't change the defined variable. The childchild class is like the past two classes, it would be like writing:

Comment: `protected int mMember; mMember = 10; mMember = 5;` Just because you change mMember's value doesn't mean it changes what type it is.

Comment: I was checking if I could access it from the sub-subclass.

Comment: You can, protected variables can be accessed by any class in the package and subclasses outside of the package. You could make an infinite amount of classes in the same package, even if it wasn't a subclass, and it would still be able to use the protected value. If you wanted to access it outside of the package, that is when you would make a subclass and work. However, if you tried to access it from a random class it wouldn't work. This is to prevent a nonrelated class from trying to access it, but allow a subclass to access it instead.

Answer (score 2):

it is `protected`, which has been inherited from parent class.

***mMember*** is declared in *ParentClass* as protected modifier. *ChildChildClass* extends *ChildClass* which extends *ParentClass*. ***The access modifier has not been changed in ChildClass and hence protected is the access modifier in ChildChildClass, which has been inherited from ParentClass***.

Have a look at [oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html) article to control access modifiers of variables.

provide **most restrictive access** to the variables unless you require un-restrictive access.

**EDIT:**

Change your code of ChildClass by redefining reduced access to mMember as follows

```
private int mMember;
```

Once you change the access modifier to private, ChildChildClass can't access mMember which is private now. You will get this error: ***`The filed ChildClass.mMember is not visible`***

Comment: Can you elaborate on that please ?

Answer (score 2):

The question is ill-formulated. You can only set the visibility on the point of declaration. At a point of use you either see the variable or not. Therefore, you cannot ask "what is the visibility when I access the variable?" but only "Can I access the variable or not?". For your case, this means: `ChildChildClass` is a (n indirect) child of `ParentClass` and `mMember` is declared `protected`, therefore it is visible within `ChildChildClass`. For more information see [the Oracle page about Access Modifiers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html).

Comment: I see what you mean, but I can clearly see that it's visible throughout the child classes, which was not my question goal. Besides, this Oracle doc does not satisfy my curiosity in this case.